# Rendering frames headless parallelly on a A10 GPU

Tags: gpu

I am trying to render 4 frames  in parallel using a blender ".blend" file. I am using blender CLI 3.4 . There is only one camera in the scene. when I try to render multiple frames using animation command they render one after other.

Animation Command:

blender -b  sample.blend -E CYCLES  -o sample1 -s 10 -e 11 -t 2  -a  -- --cycles-device CUDA

My goal is to be able to render frames parallelly, blender scene upload once and using a A10 GPU at its max capacity in headless rendering

N